# Nginx permission denied CentOS

Tags: php, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I'm trying to bind :8000 port for laravel application but getting error as per attached screenshot.

```
sudo echo "server {
listen     8000;
root /var/www/demoapp/public;
index index.php;
access_log     /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log      /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
location / {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO \$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/laravel-sample.conf

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you go to logs file and paste the error here? Also, is port 80 or 8080 working? If so, then there must be 8000 already bind.

Comment: @NoumanArshad Please check I have added port list

Comment: [Why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

This is related to SElinux, not Nginx.

```
sudo semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 8000
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: for first command giving error "ValueError: port tcp/8000 already defined" second command giving error "Unknown operation nginx"

Comment: I've updated my answer. Anyway you're supposed to ask on ServerFault, this is not a programming question.